# Filamentphp, Ho to refresh/re-calculate the count value on header

Tags: php, admin, panel, placeholder, laravel-filament

I made CommentsRelationManager for PostResource.

How I can refresh/recalculate the count value on header, whatever the comments is added or deleted.

[image]

Image note : I add a new comment, but the count value not refreshing.

This is my PostResource Form:

```
public static function form(Form $form): Form
{
    return $form
        ->schema([
            TextInput::make('title')->required(),
            TextInput::make('body')->required(),
            TextInput::make('count')
                ->reactive()
                ->label('count')
                ->disabled()
                ->placeholder(fn ($record) => $record->comments()->count())

        ]);
}
```

And this is my RelationManager

```
class CommentsRelationManager extends RelationManager
{ ...
    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('comment'),
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->headerActions([
                Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make(),
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
                Tables\Actions\DeleteAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
            ]);
    }
}
```

the last suggestion is :

```
Emit a Livewire event from the relation manager after() the Edit or Create action, 
and register a listener on the page, calling $refresh. This will refresh the value of the placeholder.
```

But It's not clear for me, and I don't know how to do it.

Anyone can help me Please...
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Following your last suggestion I have achieved the desired result with this solution:

Assuming these files exist in the Filament/Resources directory

- PostResource.php
- PostResource/Pages/EditPost.php
- PostResource/RelationManagers/CommentsRelationManager.php

In the *EditPost.php* file register the livewire event listener and use the fillForm() function to refresh the form

```
<?php

class EditPost extends EditRecord
{
    ....

    protected $listeners = ['refresh'=>'refreshForm'];

    ....

    public function refreshForm()
    {
        $this->fillForm();
    }
}
```

In the CommentsRelationManager.php file use the after() function to emit the livewire event registered before

```
<?php

....

use Filament\Resources\RelationManagers\RelationManager;

class CommentsRelationManager extends RelationManager
{
    ....

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                ....
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->headerActions([
                Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make()
                    ->after(function (RelationManager $livewire){
                        $livewire->emit('refresh');
                    })
                ,
            ])
    }    
}
```